# Automatically Size a Container div to the Dimensions of an img element inside of it using only CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have a situation where I have a div container with an image inside of it. The image is a variable asset so I never know what the height and width of the image will be. I want the div container to always fit to the size of the image and then add some padding to it... so for example if the image inside is 200px by 100px then the container should stretch to be 200px by 100px and then have 30px padding around it.

Here is an example of the CSS I'm using.. (the image is meant to be centered within the div vertically and horizontally):

```
#container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transform: translate(120px, 54px);
  padding: calc(21px/2) calc(58px/2);
}
#container:hover {
  background: pink;
}
```

Just for reference this is the html element:

```
<div id="container"><img src="image.png"></div>
```

So far I haven't been able to find any css trick that works. I tried using "fit-content" on the container, but it seems like fit-content is more for stretching the image to fit the container, not the other way around, so I resorted to using Javascript:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container"); 
container.style.width= container.querySelector('img').offsetWidth+"px";
container.style.height= container.querySelector('img').offsetHeight+"px";
```

I would rather not use JavaScript if I don't need to, so please let me know if there is a simpler way of doing this...

Comment: Did you try `display: inline-flex;` with a margin around the image instead of a padding in the container?

Comment: Do you mean that the div container should have just the dimensions of the img, but around it (outside it) it should have 'padding'  - do you mean a margin?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU, Your code is working as expected without the JavaScript:

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transform: translate(120px, 54px);
  padding: calc(21px/2) calc(58px/2);
}

#container:hover {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/400">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I just realized it was a problem in my css. I had a position absolute set on the image which was pulling it out of the document flow. It's now working as intended with a position: relative. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right this is what you want. No matter what size the image is the container will be 20px bigger.

```css
#container {
  float: left;
  background: pink;
}

#image {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  animation: size 5s linear infinite alternate;
} 

@keyframes size {
  from {width: 100px; height: auto;}
  to {width:400px; height: auto;}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<img src="https://static.toiimg.com/photo/72975551.cms" alt="pic" id="image"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I solved it...

I had this in my css:

```
#page img, #page div {position: absolute; border: 0;}
```

This was causing the image to have an absolute position which pulled it out of the document flow. Once I added position: relative to the img, it started working.

I appreciate the responses everyone. It was helpful! Thank you!